# Mosfet gate resistor vs Gain

Tags: mosfet, gain, gate-driving

I have a small question. I was doing a lab with MOSFET 2N7000. The circuit is something like the one below:[image]

There was a question asking if the gain should change if the resistor R1 was changed to 10K? The teacher said the gain should change (slightly) but I did not see any change on the Oscilloscope.

Can someone please advice whether the gain would change if R1 is increased?

Comment: Are you sure the gain change was not predicated on R1 being *before* R2? In that arrangement, the pair of resistors acts as a voltage divider, so gate voltage would drop on increasing R1, hence leading to lower gain.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, R2 connects after R1 which is used for complete switching off of the fet. But why would the gain decrease when increasing R1?

Comment: Is  this the complete circuit? or you have any biasing part? Is there anything connected to drain other than your Oscilloscope??

Comment: @nidhin, We had a supply of 5V connected to a 470ohm resistor and an LED at the drain

Comment: @DavidNorman What is the input?

Comment: @nidhin, also connected to 5V

Comment: @DavidNorman if that is the case, what did you mean by gain?

Comment: @nidhin Av = Vds/Vgs

Comment: @DavidNorman ideally mosfet gate current is zero and hence whatever be value of \$R_1\$, you will get Vgs =5V. And hence Vds/Vgs will also remain the same

Comment: @nidhin, for some students the gain increased a bit. Is it because of a small amount of current through R1 that creates a volt drop across the resistor?

Comment: @DavidNorman is it a mosfet or jfet?

Comment: @nidhin A MOSFET

Comment: @David: I suppose you mean "decreased a bit" - and that would be correct. However, I doubt if such a small change can be observed on the scope.

Comment: @LvW, it 'increased' for me it did not change but for a few groups it increased. How is that possible?

Comment: A small amount of current should pass through R1 right?

Comment: @David the amount of current through \$R_1\$ is < 10nA. \$10nA\times 10k\Omega = 0.1mV\$ is the maximum possible change in input.

Comment: @nidhin, alright, what if the value of R1 is increased to say 100K or 1M ohm, then what?

Comment: Assume that your gate is having a resistance of \$1000M\Omega\$ and you are connecting a \$1M\Omega\$ resistance in series. The potential divider will result in a drop of less .1% of supply voltage across \$R_1\$

Comment: So I was right.  The gain should remain constant no matter what the resistance at the gate is right?

Answer (score 2):

Of course the gain will change when R1 is increased but this will only be more obvious at higher frequencies. This is due, in main the to gate-source capacitance - it will form a low pass filter and reduce the signal seen at the gate as the inputted frequency increases.

Looking at the data sheet for the 2N7000, it has an input capacitance of typically 20pF and with R1 at 10kohm, the 3dB point will be about 800kHz.

Comment: @DavidNorman are you done with this question now? If so please consider formal acceptance of my answer or, if there is still something that you need clarity on, leave a comment and I'll get back to you.